# Custom search query on Wordpress page not working

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I have made a custom page for an university website where all the available scholarships are listed. User can specify city, degree, intake, scholarship type and language to search for universities with available scholarships. For this I've used advanced custom field and custom post type UI plugins and added custom fields to get data from the admin. I've tried to show the data in a tabular form in that page and it is showing the way I want to. But the problem is when i try to use the filter option for any of the above criteria(city, degree, intake, scholarship type and language) I'm getting no results but the table remains the same (The table should show the filtered data, but it isn't). I tried checking the `$args` and all the selected parameters are there. you can check the output results here https://pastebin.com/Xgmja3Yj

here's my code

```
<?php

/**
 * Template Name: Scholarship Page
 *
 * @package HelloElementor
 */

if (!defined('ABSPATH')) {
  exit; // Exit if accessed directly.
}

get_header();

?>


<div class="container">
  <h4 class="lesson-title">Browse and Apply for Scholarships</h4>
  <form action="#" method="get">

    <select name="city">
      <!-- <option value="">Select city/province</option> -->
      <option value="zhejiang">Zhejiang</option>
      <option value="zhengzhou">Zhengzhou</option>
      <option value="tshinghua">Tshinghua</option>
      <option value="peking">Peking</option>
    </select>

    <select name="scholarship_type">
      <option value="partial">Partial</option>
      <option value="full">Full</option>
    </select>

    <select name="degree">
      <option value="bachelor">Bachelor</option>
      <option value="masters">Masters</option>
      <option value="phd">PHD</option>
    </select>

    <select name="language">
      <option value="">Select Language</option>
      <option value="english">English</option>
      <option value="chinese">Chinese</option>
    </select>

    <select name="intake">
      <option value="">Select Intake</option>
      <option value="summer">Summer</option>
      <option value="winter">Winter</option>
      <option value="autumn">Autumn</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit" name="">Search</button>
  </form>

<?php
if ($_GET['city'] && !empty($_GET['city'])) {
  $city = $_GET['city'];
}

if ($_GET['scholarship_type'] && !empty($_GET['scholarship_type'])) {
  $scholarship_type = $_GET['scholarship_type'];
}

if ($_GET['degree'] && !empty($_GET['degree'])) {
  $degree = $_GET['degree'];
}

if ($_GET['language'] && !empty($_GET['language'])) {
  $language = $_GET['language'];
}

if ($_GET['intake'] && !empty($_GET['intake'])) {
  $intake = $_GET['intake'];
}
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'scholarships',
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  // 'orderby' => 'meta_value',
  'order' => 'ASC',
  'meta_query' => array(
    'relation' => "OR",
    array(
      'key' => 'cityprovince',
      'value' => $city,
      'compare' => '='
    ),

    array(
      'key' => 'scholarship',
      'value' => $scholarship_type,
      'compare' => '='
    ),

    array(
      'key' => 'degree',
      'value' => $degree,
      'compare' => '='
    ),

    array(
      'key' => 'language',
      'value' => $language,
      'compare' => 'LIKE'
    ),

    array(
      'key' => 'intake',
      'value' => $intake,
      'compare' => 'LIKE'
    )
  )
);
  
  $query = new WP_Query($args);
  
  // echo var_dump($args);
  // echo "<br>";
  // echo "<br>";
  ?>
  <div class="post clearfix">
    <table style="width:100%">
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>City/Province</th>
        <th>Major</th>
        <th>Program ID</th>
        <th>Degree</th>
        <th>Language</th>
        <th>Intake</th>
        <th>Scholarship</th>
        <th>Total Amount</th>
      </tr>
      <?php
      while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
      //echo var_dump($query);
      ?>
        <tr>
          <td><?php the_title(); ?></td>
          <td><?php the_field('cityprovince'); ?></td>
          <td><?php the_field('major'); ?></td>
          <td><?php the_field('program_id'); ?></td>
          <td><?php the_field('degree'); ?></td>
          <td><?php the_field('language'); ?></td>
          <td><?php the_field('intake'); ?></td>
          <td><?php the_field('scholarship'); ?></td>
          <td><?php the_field('total_amount'); ?></td>
        </tr>
      <?php endwhile;
      wp_reset_query(); ?>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

The `key` in `meta_query` are the field name in ACF. So any suggestions?

Comment: What was the result of ```var_dump($query);``` right above your table cells?

Comment: @Ruvee it shows all the data available for the posts, including the post name, comment no. etc. It contains all the posts. I guess that's where the problem is

Comment: So to clarify, your query returns the data but your table cells are empty? Even the title cell is empty?

Comment: @Ruvee yes my query returns the data but the table cells are not empty. They are filled with all the posts data by default.

Comment: How about changing your ```relation``` to ```AND```. ```'relation' => 'AND'```. Your getting all of the data because at least one of those filters returns true.

Comment: @Ruvee That's what i intended to do. user can select only one filed and based on that field the results will be shown. But even after setting the relation to "AND" none of the data is showing now

Comment: Can you share the ```query string/url``` that you're checking your custom query against? I suspect some of those variables are empty, therefore they return true in the filtering stage.

Comment: @Ruvee I already added it to my question, kindly check the pastebin link